# Sintaxe Python {% -- %}

Tags: python, sintaxe

Boa noite, estou fazendo o tutorial da documentação do Django e me deparei com esse código:

```
{% if latest_question_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for question in latest_question_list %}
        <li><a href="/polls/{{ question.id }}/">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No polls are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

Eu sei que nas versões anteriores se usava %s no lugar do .format ou do f string, mas esses {% -- %} eu não entendi a utilidade, alguem pode me explicar por favor?

Comment: Essas são as **template tags** do Django e dentro delas você pode realizar diversas coisas sendo uma delas, criar condicionais como no código da sua pergunta para renderizar um determinado trecho HTML apenar se a condição for verdadeira.

Comment: Ah, é uma tag expecífica do Django então?

Comment: Não posso dizer que essa forma de template é única do Django mas sim, essa é uma template onde você insere algo para realizar algo no Django. Acredito que a forma de template do framework Flask por exemplo seja a mesma, apesar delas poderem realizar coisas diferentes.

Comment: Isso não é python, é HTML. Só porque django é um framework baseado em python não quer dizer que tudo relacionado ao seu desenvolvimento vai ser em python. Django facilita bastante nossa vida dando essa abordagem "pythonica" em vários cenários, mas não tem como estender todas as funcionalidades do python para todos os componentes de um site (principalemente quando falamos de front-end) e ainda torná-lo apto aos mais diversos cenários que um framework desse tipo se propõe.